# Modular forms half integral weight: Change of multiplicatorsystem for $f \mapsto f \vert N^{-1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions, modular-forms

I have a question about a formula given in complex analysis from Freitag. In Chapter VI, right above lemma 6.5, it talks about the mapping $\left[ \Gamma[2], r/2, vv_{\vartheta}^r \right] \longrightarrow \left[ \Gamma[2], r/2, v^{(N,r)} v_{\vartheta}^r \right]$ given by $f \mapsto f \vert N^{-1}$ for a fixed  matrice $N \in \mathrm{SL_2}(\mathbb{Z})$. Right under this, it claims that for the new multiplicator system $v^{(N,r)}$ the formula 
$v^{(N,r)}(M) = v(NMN^{-1})\frac{v_{\vartheta}(NMN^{-1})}{v_{\vartheta}(M)}$ holds. Now I dont understand where this comes from. In remark 5.7  something similar is given, but there is an additional algebraic sign and the conjugation with N is the other way around. It must come somehow from the fact that $\Gamma[2]$ is a normal subgroup, but I really can't find a way to prove that.

Thanks for answers!
Hari.

Comment: I don't understand your notations. If $\gamma  = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix} \in SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ then the $[\gamma]_k$ operator (sometimes written $|_k \gamma$) is defined by $f [\gamma]_k(z) = (cz+d)^{-k} f(\gamma \cdot z) =(cz+d)^{-k} f(\frac{az+b}{cz+d})$

Comment: Well, this only holds for integral weight. For half-integral the slash notion $\vert_k \gamma$ isn't an operator anymore. You need to add a multiplicatorsystem, then $(f \vert_k \gamma )(z) = (cz + d)^{-k/2} f(\frac{az + b }{c z + d})$ becomes an operator, where the weight is $ k/2 \in \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: What do you mean ? As I said you didn't define your notations. For half-integral weight I think we replace $(cz+d)^{-1/2}$ by $\frac{\theta(\gamma . z)}{\theta(z)}$

Comment: On the left side of the mapping is the space of modularform of weight $r/2$ ($r \in \mathbb{Z}$) where the modular forms transform respectin the multplicatorsystem $vv_{\vartheta}^r$ (v is a character defined on $\Gamma[2]$ and $v(\pm M) = 1$, $M \in \Gamma[4,8]$, $v_{\vartheta}$ is the theta multiplicator system ) and the congruence subgroup $\Gamma[2]$. So for a matrice $\gamma \in \Gamma[2]$, it holds $ \left( f \vert_r \gamma \right) (z) = vv_{\vartheta}^{-r}(cz + d)^{-r/2} f( \gamma z)$. On the right sight is a similar space, just the character of the multiplicatorsystem permutates.

Comment: I don't think that holds in general. There is a $\pm$ missing for the new factor.

Comment: I meant if $f(z) = j(\gamma,z)^{-k} f(\gamma . z)$ for $\gamma \in \Gamma$ and $g(z) = f(\alpha. z)$ then $g(z) =   j(\gamma,\alpha. z)^{-k} g(\alpha^{-1}\gamma \alpha . z)= J( \beta , z)^{-k} g(\beta. z)$ where $\beta=\alpha^{-1}\gamma \alpha \in \alpha^{-1}\Gamma \alpha$ and $J(\beta,z) =  j(\alpha\beta \alpha^{-1},\alpha. z)$. Why would you need to say something more ? If $j(\gamma,z) = \phi(\gamma) j_2(\gamma,z)$ then $J(\beta,z) =  \Phi(\beta) j_2(\alpha\beta \alpha^{-1},\alpha. z)$ with $\Phi(\beta) = \phi(\alpha\beta \alpha^{-1})$ a character on $\alpha^{-1}\Gamma \alpha$.

Comment: I don't really understand your notation, is $\gamma.z := \frac{az + b}{cz +d}$?. If yes, I don't understand where your second line comes from?

Comment: Yes $\gamma,\alpha,\beta \in SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ or $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ and $z \in \mathbb{C},\Im(z) > 0$. It comes from replacing $z$ by $\alpha.z$ and $f$ by $g$ in $f(z) = j(\gamma,z)^{-k} f(\gamma . z)$.

Comment: Where it becomes complicated is when averaging over cosets $\Gamma \setminus \Gamma'$ for some subgroup $\Gamma'$ (Hecke operators)